# Is tracing on Graphics Tablets possible?

Tags: drawing-tablet

I'm totally new to using tablets, and to digital art at all, and (yes, I am aware that this question may sound stupid) I was wondering, if I was to put one of my paper drawnings on top of the tablets surface, and re-trace over it, if it was possible that the tablet would still pick it up, and make it easier for me to re-draw my artwork digitally, without having to completely start over?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to put paper down between your stylus and tablet. Older models even came with a clear cover for this use.

Comment: Also because your normal tip does not actually draw. It is possible to get inking tips so that you could ink the nondigital original and get a digital version at the same time.